# How to skip spring authentication for specific method of controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

How to skip a specific method from being authenticated in spring mvc. My `spring_security.xml` file contains:

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
      <intercept-url pattern="/logout" access="permitAll"/>
      <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll"/>
      <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
      <logout logout-success-url="/logoutPage" logout-url="/logout" />
      <form-login authentication-failure-url="/login?auth=fail"
          login-page="/login"
          login-processing-url="/loginPage" 
          password-parameter="password"
          username-parameter="username"
      />
</http>
<global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" pre-post-annotations="enabled" />
```

Now how can I skip authentication for a method defined below using `annotation`

```
@Controller
public class DataController {

    @PreAuthorize("permitAll")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/data/info", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Content-Type=application/json")
    public @ResponseBody String getDetails() {
        // some code
    }
}
```

What I used is not working. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There are two level of security in spring security :

- URL based security managed by `intercept-url` elements
- method based security mainly managed with `PreAuthorize` annotations.

You can mix the two, and method security can be used to very refined rules particurlarly with ACLs, and can be applied on service or model methods, but it cannot be used to overwrite URL based restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. `intercept-url` is evaluated before controller annotations.

However you can solve it by adding following to your xml:

```xml
<intercept-url pattern="/data/info" access="permitAll"/>
```

The `@PreAuthorize("permitAll")` makes no sense since it basically is a no-op.

Comment: But isn't their any annotation which can be used instead of defining in xml becuase I have so many method which require `permitAll`

Comment: You can use annotation(s) instead of xml, but you can't override rules defined in xml by annotations.

Answer (score 0):

try using something like that

```
<http pattern="/data/info**" security="none"/>
```